# dot products of rows and columns

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices, a (mxn), and b (nxp). For each n, I would like to multiply the nth column of a with the nth row of b, giving me n (mxp) matrices. I would then like to 'collapse' these matrices into a single (mxp) matrix by taking the mean of each element in the matrix. Is there a reasonably efficient way (as in no loops) to do this in numpy?

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm. Surely in step one, what you describe as 'taking the dot product' is just ab i.e. matrix multiplication?

Comment: Are you able to confirm what the output should look like, e.g. using the example arrays `a = np.arange(2*3).reshape(2,3)` and `b = np.arange(3*4).reshape(3,4)`?

Comment: You are correct, I updated my original question.

Comment: well if you are doing this then you will only have 1 m*p matrix and not n as you suggest, so I am not sure what the idea that follows is (apologies for being pedantic - just don't want to give you the wrong answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot product does the multiplication followed by a sum, producing a (m,p) array.  If you want the mean instead of sum, just divide by `n`, the number of items you are summing.

```
np.dot(a,b)/n
```

Comment: Yeah, I was all ready to go with `np.einsum('ij,jk->ijk', a, b).mean(axis=1)` before I realized that was way more complicated than we needed..